# How to specify a VAR model in R with non-stationary, stationary, and trend-stationary variables?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity, vector-autoregression, cointegration

I have a multivariate time series and I want to estimate a VAR model. I tested for unit roots with the ADF and KPSS test and concluded that some variables are non-stationary, while others are stationary around a non-zero mean, and again others are stationary around a deterministic trend (i.e., trend-stationary).

After that I tested for cointegration of the non-stationary variables with the Johansen test and as I failed to reject the null hypothesis of no cointegration, I took the first difference of those variables. That is, the variables now have different lenghts.

I am not quite sure how I can specify the VAR model correctly in such a case as I have differenced variables without a constant, variables with a constant and variables with a trend.

```
library(vars)
VAR(y, p = 1, type = c("const", "trend", "both", "none"), season = NULL, exogen = NULL, lag.max = NULL, ic = c("AIC", "HQ", "SC", "FPE"))
```

My guess would be either

1. to set `type="both"` when specifying the `VAR` model to account for the trend and constant, or
2. to detrend the trend-stationary variables and set `type="const"`, or
3. leave the trend-stationary variables as they are, set `type="const"`, and include the trend as an exogenous variable in the VAR model with help of the `exogen` argument. However, I am not aware how I can achieve this in R. Do I have to decompose the trend-stationary variables, take their trends and include them seperately as exogenous variables?

Thank you!

Comment: @Richard Hardy As it seems that you are one of the most experienced in this field on this platform, I would truly appreciate any comments or suggestions you may give me.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. I am a little overwhelmed with work at university this fall, so I skip more questions on VAR and related topics than I used to. Sorry about that.

Comment: @RichardHardy Alright, thank you anyway for your reply :)